# Why listview receiving some large icons and some small?

Tags: java, android, json, xml, listview

i am receiving some Icons and text from server Using json string, but there is the problem that some icons display very large size and some small.
i want that all icons should be display small size no one should be large icons in list view.

here is my custom_adapter xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_mainID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tipster.Tipster_adapter" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_tipsterIconID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llot1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_text11" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_total_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_proofinglink_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View Proofing"
        android:textColor="#219BCC"
        android:textColorLink="#6D7578" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_sitelink_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get More Detail"
        android:textColor="#219BCC" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my `Tipster_adapter.java` code

```
package tipster;
 //import

public class Tipster_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Tipster_list>tipslist;
@SuppressLint("Instantiatable")
 public Tipster_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Tipster_list> tipslist) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.tipslist = tipslist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return tipslist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView icon;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView total;
    public TextView proofingLink;
    public TextView siteLink;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tipster_adapter,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_tipsterIconID);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_tipsterID);
        holder.total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_tipsterID);
        holder.proofingLink = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_proofinglink_tipsterID);
        holder.proofingLink.setFocusable(true);
        holder.proofingLink.requestFocus();
        holder.siteLink = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sitelink_tipsterID);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Tipster_list services=tipslist.get(position);
    Picasso.with(context).load(services.getImage()).into(holder.icon);
    Log.d("Url",services.getImage());
    holder.name.setText(services.getName());
    holder.total.setText(services.getTotal());

    final String getproofing=services.getProofinglink();
    final String getsite=services.getSitelink();
    holder.proofingLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tipster_webview.class);
             intent.putExtra("gettproofing_URl",getproofing);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "proofing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    holder.proofingLink.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(event.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A2B4BA")); //dark
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#219BCC")); //Light-blue
                break;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });

    holder.siteLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tipster_webview.class);
                         intent.putExtra("site",getsite);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

    holder.siteLink.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(event.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A2B4BA")); //dark
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#219BCC")); //Light-blue
                break;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });



    return convertView;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are setting your image height and width on your `ImageView` to `wrap_content` which makes the `ImageView` as big or as small as the image you are giving it.

If you want them to have a fixed width and height you should give the `ImageView` a fixed width and height.

```
<!--I would probably use a dimen resource to define the value 24dp-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_tipsterIconID"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"  
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: i got solution from your answer @user3331142

Answer (score 1):

Change the layout height and width parameters from wrap content to fixed values. Wrap content will choose the height and width of the images input which will be random, the reason for multiple sizes. :)